# Telethon python: how can i use pattern correctly for new message?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I all,
i want use patter for **exclude** words with pattern, can you help me?

```
list_words_to_exclude = [word1, word2, word3]
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, from_users=lista_canali, pattern=list_words_to_exclude ))
async def gestione_eventi(evento):
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a manual filter

```
list_words_to_exclude = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

async def filter(event):
    for word in list_words_to_exclude :
         if word in event.raw_text:
             return True
     return False
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, from_users=lista_canali, func=filter ))
async def gestione_eventi(evento):
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.common.EventBuilder) you can simply pass in a filter callback to `func` parameter of `events.NewMessage`:

```
func (callable, optional)
```

> A callable (async or not) function that should accept the event as
> input parameter, and return a value indicating whether the event
> should be dispatched or not (any truthy value will do, it does not
> need to be a bool).

So in your case that could be:

```py
list_words_to_exclude = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

# custom filter function
def filter_words(event):
    for word in list_words_to_exclude:
         if word in event.raw_text:
             return False  # do not dispatch this event 
     return True  # dispatch all other events


# pass in the filter function as an argument to the `func` parameter
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, from_users=lista_canali, func=filter_words))
async def gestione_eventi(evento):
    # other logic here  
    ...
```